# Having Several Levels in columns Python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, factors, levels

I have several columns in a dataframe- each with several factors/levels in it (10+) . In every column, 3-4 factors make up 85-90% of the values. I have several columns in the data. Going through each column and making dummy variables of the top 3-4 would take a lot of time. Simply putting get_dummies would increase size of data exponentially. Is there any useful way that can be suggested in which I can automatically take the top 3-4 factors as dummy variables pushing the rest into ‘Others’ category , for each column? I am using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the `nlargest` by column, and replace values not in the top 3 with other as you are creating your dummies.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e'],
                  'size': ['s','s','s','m','m','s','l','l','xl']})

for col in ['type','size']:
    df = pd.concat([df,
                    pd.get_dummies(df[col].replace(df.loc[~df[col].isin(df[col].value_counts().nlargest(3).index)][col].unique(),
                                                   'other'), 
                                   prefix=col)],
                   axis=1)
```

Output

```
  type size  type_a  type_b  type_c  type_other  size_l  size_m  size_other  \
0    a    s       1       0       0           0       0       0           0   
1    a    s       1       0       0           0       0       0           0   
2    a    s       1       0       0           0       0       0           0   
3    b    m       0       1       0           0       0       1           0   
4    b    m       0       1       0           0       0       1           0   
5    b    s       0       1       0           0       0       0           0   
6    c    l       0       0       1           0       1       0           0   
7    d    l       0       0       0           1       1       0           0   
8    e   xl       0       0       0           1       0       0           1   

   size_s  
0       1  
1       1  
2       1  
3       0  
4       0  
5       1  
6       0  
7       0  
8       0
```